# Two default methods calling each other

Tags: oop, design-patterns, java-8, default-method

I have an interface like this:

```
    public interface Foobar
    {
        default void foo( Bar bar )
        {
            foo( bar, 1 );
        }

        default void foo( Bar bar, int n )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
            {
                foo( bar );
            }
        }
    }
```

In the beginning I thought it'd be fine just as:

```
    default void foo( byte[] b )
    {
        foo( b, 0, b.length );
    }

    void foo( byte[] b, int off, int len );
```

My problem is that I want to execute `foo` either once or `n` times.
Any implementing class may override either one or both of them. (The second method exists for batching purposes in a performance critical system)

But it seems that my solution using `default` isn't good style as it is possible to override none of them and calling either leads to an infinite loop (and eventually to a StackOverflow).

So, my question is: What would be good OOP style compromise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IFoo interface can look like this -

```
public interface IFoo {

    default void foo(Bar bar, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            foo(bar);
        }
    }

    void foo(Bar bar);

}
```

and your Foo class implementing the IFoo interface can be like this -

```
public class Foo implements IFoo{

    @Override
    public void foo(Bar bar) {
        // process foo logic

    }

}
```

You do not need to enforce the single loop logic inside the interface, instead the call the foo straight away.

Comment: "//process foo logic" is what I want the implementing class to do

Comment: If you want to force that behaviour to the implementing class, then no need to keep it as `default`. However, `foo(Bar)` must be implemented at the interface level as `default`.

Comment: If you think, this answer works for you, let me know, I will edit the answer so it becomes more readable.

Comment: Of course I could remove the default but the reason interface level method defaults exist is for the sake of convenience. I will remove it if I get no better suggestion.

Comment: You can have one more more `default void fooLoop(Bar,n)` which will have the looping logic, while the actual foo logic can be enforced to all implementing classes

Comment: You mean, I should remove the first method and call foo(bar, 1) instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120350/discussion-between-tejas-unnikrishnan-and-androbin).